# Error: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length when using super method

Tags: java, arguments, super

```
    public class Pizza
    {
        private int itemNum;
        private String size;
        private String base;
        private String extraCheese;
        private String extraGarlic;

        Pizza(int itemNum, String size, String base, String extraCheese, String extraGarlic)
        {
            this.itemNum = itemNum;
            this.size = size;
            this.base = base;
            this.extraCheese = extraCheese;
            this.extraGarlic = extraGarlic;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "Pizza: " + itemNum + ", " + size + ", " + base + ", " + extraCheese + ", " + extraGarlic;
        }

}
```

---

This is the parent class, and the following class is the derived class.

---

```
class Curry extends Pizza
{
    String curryType;

    Curry(int itemNum, String size, String curryType)
    {
        // Error occurs here
        super(itemNum, size);
        this.curryType = curryType;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        // return "Curry: " + itemNum + ", " + size + ", "  + curryType;
        return "Curry";
    }
}
```

---

> required: int,String,String,String,String   found: int,String
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error

Comment: What don't you understand? You're calling a constructor that needs 5 arguments with only two.

Comment: Does that mean I need to add more arguments (even if I don't need them) to be able to call the constructor?

Comment: Yes. The base class needs Strings that describes the base, the extraCheese and the extraGarlic you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing too few things to your `super` constructor.  The constructor for `Pizza` expects 5 things and you're only providing 2.

If it's the case that you don't need the extraneous 3 arguments, remove them from the parent constructor.  This both simplifies the call and ensures that the object is created with simply what it needs to exist before you mutate any other state information on it.

Alternatively, if those arguments are needed for the parent class, you could always create another constructor that accepts just those values:

```
public Pizza(int itemNum, String size) {
    this(itemNum, size, null, null, null);
}
```

...but depending on how your program is intended to work, this may introduce spurious `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: But I need those 5 arguments for the Pizza class. I do get that it will simplify the call though.

Comment: If you need them for the `Pizza` class, then you need them for the `Curry` class.  I'll introduce an alternative approach though.

Comment: @pk. Inheritance means that a Curry *is a* pizza. So, if a Pizza needs a `base` String to exist, then a Curry also needs one. Where I live a Curry is not a pizza at all. So Curry should probably not extend Pizza. A Margarita or a VeggiePizza could be a Pizza.

Comment: @JBNizet:  You're absolutely right, but [curry pizza is totally a thing.](http://www.pillsbury.com/recipes/chicken-curry-pizza/2df2b7b2-c3db-4df6-80c8-9517903f5138)

Comment: Here's what a Curry is, where I live: http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette-photo_curry-d-agneau-facile_14030.aspx

Comment: @JBNizet:  Mind you, I'm making the quantum leap that they actually intended to mean it's a curry pizza, not a legitimate curry dish.  Otherwise, what they're saying or doing makes no sense.

Comment: Haha, glad this question is leading to other discussions.